# C++ class function not using the correct values in `this` but it does when using an "external" object

Tags: c++, class

I have an ESP32 project where I have a class called `Card` which represents an NFC tag. This class 3 fields, id, value, and time_saved. The class also has a function to save the tag to a database stored in an SD. When the module reads a card, it returns its uid. Then, it creates a pointer to a `Card`. Then, it searches the uid in the database. If it does not exist, the program asks if the user wants to save the card. When they say yes and input the message, the program uses the `Card` function `save_card`. Here is where the problem lies.

Inside the class function `save_card`, and only in this function, does the card's id suddenly transform to `B`. It goes from a 6 bytes long string representation to `B`. And that's not all. If the tag has a 4-byte uid, this problem does not occur.

I am going to show code for a better understanding, and then explain what I have done to try to find the root of the problem.

```cpp
void loop() {
  // Get RFID tag
  string tag = read_RFID(&rfid);
  if (tag.empty()) return;

  // Query database
  Card *card;
  try {
    card = Card(tag).select_card();
  } catch (const runtime_error &e) {
    Serial.println(e.what());
    return;
  }

  // If the operation switch is high, enter edition mode
  if (digitalRead(operation_pin) == HIGH) {
    edition_mode(card);
    return;
  }

  // If the operation switch is low, enter playback mode
  playback_mode(card);
  return;
}

void edition_mode(Card *card) {
  // Check if the card is saved in the database
  if (!card->get_value().empty()) {
    Serial.println("\nCard already saved");
    card->print();
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("Tag not found\n");
  Serial.println("Do you want to save the tag? (y/n)");

  // Wait for the user to enter a character
  while (Serial.available() == 0) delay(100);
  char c = Serial.read();

  // If the user doesn't want to save the card, return
  if (c != 'y') {
    Serial.println("Tag not saved");
    return;
  };

  // Ask the user for a message
  Serial.println("Enter a message to save to the tag:");
  string message = "";
  while (Serial.available() == 0) delay(100);
  while (Serial.available() > 0) message += (char)Serial.read();

  // Check if the message is empty
  if (message.empty()) {
    Serial.println("Message cannot be empty");
    return;
  }

  // Save the message to the tag
  try {
    card->save_card(message, format_now(rtc.now()));
  } catch (const runtime_error &e) {
    Serial.println(e.what());
    return;
  }

  // Print the message
  Serial.println("New Tag");
  card->print();
  return;
}

int Card::save_card(string value, string datetime) {
  sqlite3 **db = open_db();

  // Prepare the statement
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db, "INSERT INTO card (id, value, date_created) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", -1, &statement, NULL) !=
      SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close_v2(*db);
    throw runtime_error("Unable to prepare: " + string(sqlite3_errmsg(*db)));
  }

  // Bind the tag id, value, and datetime created
  const char *values[3] = {this->get_id().c_str(), value.c_str(), datetime.c_str()};
  const char *tags[3] = {"id", "value", "datetime"};

  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, i + 1, values[i], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
      sqlite3_finalize(statement);
      sqlite3_close_v2(*db);
      throw runtime_error("Unable to bind " + string(tags[i]) + ": " + string(sqlite3_errmsg(*db)));
    }
  }

  // Execute the statement
  if (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close_v2(*db);
    throw runtime_error("Unable to execute: " + string(sqlite3_errmsg(*db)));
  }

  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  sqlite3_close_v2(*db);

  this->value = value;
  this->time = datetime;

  return 1;
}
```

So that's the relevant code to the problem. When I print the card's id in the `loop` or the `edition_mode` functions, it prints the correct thing. But when I print it inside the `save_card` function, it just prints B. Now, I wanted to make sure this was only happening inside this function, and it is. In the other class functions the ID is the same that was saved from the beginning.
Another thing worth noting is that I printed the address of the class pointers in the 3 functions (`save_card`, `loop`, and `edition_mode`), and they were all the same. However, when I printed the address of `card->get_id()`, it was the same in `loop` and in `edition_mode`, but something completely different in `save_card`. I tried the same thing between `edition_mode` and other class functions, and while the addresses are not the same, they just change the penultimate character.

I am not an expert in C++ (clearly) so I don't know what else to do. I tried finding these addresses to see if it changed anything, but I don't think it did. I also don't think this has anything to do with the ESP32, rather than with me and my foolishness. I hope this is well explained, and I find someone to help me. Thanks to all for your time!

Edit:
Someone asked what `select_card()` returned. Here is the code:

```cpp
Card *Card::select_card() {
  sqlite3 **db = open_db();

  // Prepare the statement
  sqlite3_stmt *statement;
  if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(*db, "SELECT value, date_created FROM card WHERE id = ?;", -1, &statement, NULL) !=
      SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_close_v2(*db);
    throw runtime_error("Unable to prepare: " + string(sqlite3_errmsg(*db)));
  }

  // Bind the value
  if (sqlite3_bind_text(statement, 1, this->id.c_str(), -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT) != SQLITE_OK) {
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close_v2(*db);
    throw runtime_error("Unable to bind: " + string(sqlite3_errmsg(*db)));
  }

  // Get the columns
  string value;
  while (sqlite3_step(statement) != SQLITE_DONE) {
    value = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0);
    string datetime = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1);
    sqlite3_finalize(statement);
    sqlite3_close_v2(*db);
    this->value = value;
    this->time = datetime;
    return this;
  }

  sqlite3_finalize(statement);
  sqlite3_close_v2(*db);
  return this;
}
```

Comment: `card = Card(tag).select_card()` looks very suspicious.  What does `select_card` return?  How is it allocated?  Are you sure its lifetime is sufficient?

Comment: Can you create a standalone code that compiles or give a link to github where your code? Also mark with comments where your code fails

Comment: I added `select_card`'s code so you can see everything @Miles Budnek
Either way, the object works everywhere else, so I don't see what's the problem.

Comment: @nvn I can't give you GitHub access since I don't want to free the code, I am sorry. However, I think what I just updated is going to help you understand. Please understand why I can't free the code. Thanks

Comment: `Card(tag).select_card() ` seems like guaranteed UB as it returns `this`, a pointer to `Card` that gets destoyed next moment.

Comment: Why does it gets destroyed? @ALX23z

Comment: Cause that's a temporary object. Their lifetime ends after the line was executed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your program's behavior is undefined.

```
card = Card(tag).select_card();
```

Here you create a temporary `Card` object and then assign a pointer to it (via `select_card`) to `card`.  The temporary `Card` object's lifetime ends at the end of the full expression and `card` is left pointing to nothing.  Any further attempt to dereference `card` leads to undefined behavior.

I'm not sure why you feel you need to use a pointer here at all.  I don't see any particular reason to do so.  Just create a local `Card` object:

```
Card card(tag);
try {
    card.select_card();
} catch (const runtime_error &e) {
    Serial.println(e.what());
    return;
}
```

Comment: I used a pointer because when I pass the card into the `edition_mode` function, if it’s not a pointer, it doesn’t work, the fields suddenly turn blank. However, I can create the card like you said and then pass a pointer to that, maybe that’ll work. I’ll keep you updated. Thanks! Can you explain why what i was doing is wrong?

Comment: Ok so I did what you said and now it works. Thanks!
Can you explain why is it a temporary object? I am guessing that it is because it needs to free up the memory, but I just want to confirm.

Comment: @Joaquin It's a temporary object because that's how the language works.  The simplest way to think about it is that if an object doesn't have a name or get created by a `new` expression then it's temporary.  There are a few exceptions, but that's the basic rule.